# How to check if a specific option was selected from a group of selects

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table built with "n" number of rows. On each row I have a select list with the same options.
I need to check using jQuery if any of those selects has a particular option selected.
For example, I need to know if any of the followings is selected with the value 2.:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
     <select class="fee-type" name="fee-type-options">
    <option value="0">*Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <select class="fee-type" name="fee-type-options">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">*Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
...
```

I tried many things like the following, but in this case I just get the value of the first item select:

```
$('input[name="fee-type-options option:selected"]').val()
```

Comment: You should get the value of the Select element. `$(".fee-type").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
 $("select").on('change', function () {
   $("select").val(); // will return selected value
 })
```

i hope it was useful :)

Comment: Thanks but I need to check it in the submit action not in the change since we have pre-populated values